# How to stay in shape during a workout hiatus?

Tags: workout, maintenance

I had a retinal hemorrhage a week ago and was told by my doctor to not work out for a month.

What can I do to minimize the amount of muscle that is atrophied over that month, without stressing/over-exerting myself?

*Any tag recommendations?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Rest.

You won't see appreciable muscle loss in a month. Keep your calorie intake at maintenance and take it easy.

The alternative is light exercise against your doctors instructions that could risk your eyesight.

Answer (score 1):

Keep moving without straining yourself. You're not going to want to do anything that's going to raise your blood pressure, but there's a lot of movement that can be done without exerting yourself that will nonetheless keep your body in the spirit of movement. Even doing something so simple as taking a long walk every night around your neighborhood, or doing walking laps in your house, will help.

Answer (score -2):

Blood flow restriction is one technique that is often recommended.
http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11128848
http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18379217

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15560)

Comment: Actually it does. It's a technique used to minimize muscle loss during injury or the such.Maybe you are unfamiliar with what bfr is, however you should ask or Google it before you criticize something

Comment: BFR is mainly used during actual training, can you provide evidence that it helps when not training? And "prove that it doesn't" isn't acceptable. Burden of proof is on your claim that it helps.

Comment: Never claimed to have proof, I said it's often recommended. If you take a moment and look around you will see many articles that will suggest incorporating bfr while injured. I felt it valuable to pass that along